Can object height be negative?
Can object height be negative in an optical system? I've tried thinking of a way it can be but I haven't found anything.

Yes, if the object goes below the optical axis then its reasonable to treat it as having negative height.

Yes. In optical systems, object's height can be considered negative when the object is below the optical axis that's,if the object is inverted or its position is defined below the axis then, it is assigned a negative height.
This is not about the physical height of the object but rather its position relative to the optical axis.
